# Database not completely updated in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have a migration called **create user**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column :username, :string,        :limit => 25, :default => "", :null => false
      t.column :hashed_password, :string, :limit => 40, :default => "", :null => false
      t.column :first_name, :string,      :limit => 25, :default => "", :null => false
      t.column :last_name, :string,       :limit => 40, :default => "", :null => false
      t.column :email, :string,           :limit => 50, :default => "", :null => false
      t.column :display_name, :string,    :limit => 25, :default => "", :null => false
      t.column :user_level, :integer,     :limit => 3,  :default => 0,  :null => false
    end

 User.create(:username=>'test',:hashed_password=>'test',:first_name=>'test',:last_name=>'test',:email=>'test@test.com',:display_name=> 'test',:user_level=>9)  
  end
end
```

When I run `rake db:migrate` the table is created with the columns as mentioned above but the test data are not there

```
mysql>select * from users;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT** I just dropped the whole database and restarted the migration and now it is showing the following error.

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: username, hashed_password, first_name, last_name, email, display_name, user_level
```

What am I doing wrong please help?
Thank you.

Comment: Does the `User.create` statement gives validation errors when you change it to `User.create!` (with an exclamation mark)?

Comment: edited the question can you please help me

Comment: put this in user.rb attr_accessible :username, :hashed_password, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :display_name, :user_level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
attr_accessible :username, :hashed_password, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :display_name, :user_level
```

to your user.rb

Answer (score 0):

That's Rails way of prohibiting users to create or update objects via a param hash.  You need to specify your User attributes as `attr_accessible` in your model:

example :

```
class User
 attr_accessible :username, :firstname (etc)
end
```

Read more about Mass Assignment [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment).

Answer (score 0):

just to complete the answer about testing environment. You can run `rake db:test:prepare` to check the migrations and load schema !